# Rate widget in panels not working

Tags: panels, rating

I'm using the votingapi and rate modules but I have some issues with those modules and panels.

I'm using panels to render the node view. I added content using node > Rate widget. Everything looks fine viewing the node, even if I use the rate widget in the node.

The problem comes when I refresh the page. The rating is not anymore in the widget. That's weird because the value of the rating is stored in the votingapi_vote table, even if I show the widget using views it displays the correct rating, but not with panels.

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer. The problem occurs when the option "Use source translation" is checked in the Rate configuration section. Here is a patch to solve the problem [source translation option on untranslated nodes causes 0 votes display](https://www.drupal.org/node/1931868)